# device/.../libaudioamp/audio_amplifier.c:20:10: fatal error: 'platform.h' file not found #include <platform.h>

Tags: android, android-source, cyanogenmod, building

I have this error when trying to build an AOSP rom using cm device trees. I solved other errors but now I'm stuck at this one. Can someone help me? 
This is the full log
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9vudYbIfwbDNmJzMk5ZQWRwMWc

Answer (score 0):

Which rom is it?

Also, sync this

```
https://github.com/LineageOS/android_hardware_qcom_audio/tree/cm-14.1-caf-8974
https://github.com/LineageOS/android_hardware_qcom_display/tree/cm-14.1-caf-8974
https://github.com/LineageOS/android_hardware_qcom_media/tree/cm-14.1-caf-8974
```

(Qualcomm doesn't support MSM8974 anymore)

The file you are looking for is here (https://github.com/LineageOS/android_hardware_qcom_audio/blob/cm-14.1-caf-8974/hal/msm8974/platform.h)

Comment: ABC ROM based on pure nexus. U saying i need only those los trees for my caf aosp rom?